# Communication between MassTransit and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I would like to make a java application and a .net application communicate through a queue.

I wanted to use MassTransit but it is not available in java so in the java code we use RabbitMQ directly to send data serialized in xml into the required wrapper with data (like the message type). I also had to make sure to add the "Content-Type" header: "application/vnd.masstransit+xml". That works fine, the data is sent by the java app, received by the .Net app and correctly deserialized.

The issue is that, now, I also need to send back a response to the java app but not sure how to proceed.

Can I use MassTransit to also send a message back ?

Do I have to use the directly RabbitMQ  ?

Is there a better way to handle the situation ?

Thanks in advance for all the help you could provide me, it would be really appreciated

Comment: There is a Java project that can serialize in a compatible format to MassTransit, but it's send/publish only. https://github.com/amhest/MassTransit-CrossTown

Comment: I saw it but seeing the project was not maintained or finished I tried to send the data with RabbitMq directly and it worked correctly. Now I'd like to have it work the other way arround. But thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/NordPool/JTransitLight

Comment: JTRansitLight has moved or been discontinued.